# Magento 2 theme HELP

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-2.2.1, parent-child-theme

Not long ago I made my first Magento 2 custom/child theme so that my website 
changes won't be erased when I upgrade to another version.

I now want to override some core Magento 2 files that I need to make changes 
in.

The official theme document on Magento's website makes no sense to me.

For days I have looked at many different guides on how to override the core 
Magento 2 files, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around where I should place 
the copied files in my theme folders so that I can modify them.  Two of the 
files (default.xml) have the same name but have different content.

This is pretty much the only thing I have done so far, because of my ignorance and confusion:
I placed a modified default.xml file to customize the footer links in the 
/Magento_Theme/layout folder of my theme, but when I enable my theme, the 
links at the top and bottom of the homepage turned light blue, and the mini 
cart doesn't display any items that are in the cart, and wouldn't let me 
"Proceed to Checkout" when pressing that button.

Obviously, there is something that I am missing.

Am I only supposed to copy files from the /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank folder, or the /pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US folder?

Does anyone know of a good newbie/dummy guide to theming in Magento 2, or can 
just tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.

---

I am using Magento 2.2.1

My custom/child theme is inheriting from the Blank theme.

This is my theme structure: /app/design/frontend/ABC/ABC_Theme/, then inside 
that folder are etc, Magento_Theme, media, web, composer.json, 
registration.php, and theme.xml.

---

Below are the files that I need to put in my theme folders and modify them, 
and what I want to do with them:

**To change the Captcha noise level:**
/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/image.php

**To change the text for the captcha from "Please type the letters below":** 
/vendor/magento/module-captcha/view/frontend/templates/default.phtml

**To change some of the words in the notice:**
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml

**To change "What's on your mind", and "Jot us a note and we'll get back to you as quickly as possible" in the contact us page:** 
public_html/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

**To remove the "Orders and Returns" link from the footer, and to remove the 
sales-guest-form-link:** 
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

**To customize the popup's text:** 
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/authentication-
popup.html

**or should it be from**

/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html

**To customize the links in the footer:** 
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Should all of these files go somewhere in the 'Magento_Theme' folder or 
folders of their own?